# Logging time zone aware events

Tags: mysql, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

I know pages and pages have been written on this topics, however, I need to clarify this issue, and be sure I'm doing what is sensible.

The users of my app can be in any part of the world. I log a number of events/actions a user performs on my app. I want to be able to see what events/actions a user made in it's own time zone, or a timezone of my choosing.

At the moment, my app is sending the date and time of the event **in UTC** in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" and also, in a separate field, the time zone offset in minutes (e.g. -120 or +60).

When I get the events, I store them in MySQL in the following way: I use a DATETIME column to store the date and time of the event as is; I use an INT column to store the offset.

When I want to do a select and get back the event in the user's time zone, I just do:

```
SELECT cdate + INTERVAL tz_offset MINUTES FROM events WHERE uid=123;
```

I believe this is the best option for me, and offers versatility.

What do you think?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `tz_offset`? Is it captured for every uses as an event happens?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, tz_offset is the difference in minutes to UTC and is sent with every event.

Comment: "I use a DATETIME column to store the date and time of the event as is" --- it means it is already in the user's timezone, isn't it? In the timezone of the user who emitted an event.

Comment: @zerkms No, the date time from the app is sent in UTC. Sorry for not mentioning that important detail. Edited above.

Comment: Okay, it will work then. The alternative could be to use `timestamp` data type instead. In that case you wouldn't have to do anything to convert the time.

Comment: @zerkms How so? do you mean on select? wouldn't it convert to my timezone?

Comment: oh my bad, "in the user's time zone" means for the original user. Then yep, only this

Comment: Great, thanks for clearing this out for me!